# Improve Mongodb insert operation using c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using MongoDB C# driver v2.6.1 and inserting the document in multi threaded environment. I want to improve the write operation. This is how i am doing.

```
IMongoDatabase mongodb = iapplicationhelper.GetDatabase("TransactionLogDB");
var col = mongodb.GetCollection<TransactionRequestModel>("TransactionLog");
col.InsertOne(model);
```

Is there any other approach to fasten the write operation?

Comment: Improve in what way? Make the code shorter? Make it run faster? Cut down on network traffic?

Comment: basically i have to make the write operation as fast as possible. what approach should i use when parallel insertion is being done.